# disable whitespace on top when scrolling down or up

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, webview

I'm trying to disable the whitespace or the ability to over scroll top or bottom. I will be attaching an image to better describe my question. Also another example is any website when over scrolling. what I'm trying to accomplish is image zoom like the apps.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkGQd.png)

Answer (score 0):

Show your code for better understandings.

```
<body style=“margin:0;”>
```